# Display a data from an array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I just want to ask how to display the data from an array like this? [Here's the link](https://github.com/F-Derakhshani/yith-woocommerce-points-and-rewards-premium/blob/04207f2aa9a2b75d34cdf59aef63cf73e6729a08/plugin-options/messages-options.php)

This is my first time seeing an array like this long and I am confused. I tried getting the data from the `cart_message` and I get an `array` as a result. I'm sure this is the wrong format to get it. I am a newbie when it comes to this.

```
$messages['cart_message'];
```

Update:

Here's what I am trying to do.

I am trying to display the string on the `cart_message`

I want to display the text on the `cart_message` on the side cart template. So, to do that, I thought it will display if I use this filter

```
$yith_message = apply_filters( 'yith_ywpar_panel_messages_options', $messages);

 echo '<pre>'; var_dump($yith_message); echo '</pre>';
```

The result is `Null`

Comment: What is the element of the array that you want to access? Do you want to get the string "Cart message"?

Comment: Yes sir, the string message which I believe is the "std".

Comment: what do you men to display the data? did you mean you want to display the message array from the parent array?

Comment: Hi @Jerson,  thanks for the comment, I just updated the post. Apologies for the confusion. Hope the updated post clarifies it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var_export($messages);
```

More info: [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)